# Not able to click on a full screen using Robotium

Tags: android, junit, robotium

I have a screen, which is a full screen with android navigation bar hidden on the app that I am testing using Robotium. When I try to click on the only button on that screen I get (java.lang.SecurityException: Injecting to another application requires INJECT_EVENTS permission) error. This is at the line solo.clickOnView(solo.getView(R.id.activate_homeBtn));

Interestingly, when I touch the screen with my finger once(the android navigation bar becomes active now), then the Robotium is able to click on the button. How Can I click on the button without touching the screen manually. Below is the failure trace and the test code.

junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: Click at (360.0, 592.0) can not be completed! (java.lang.SecurityException: Injecting to another application requires INJECT_EVENTS permission)
at com.robotium.solo.Clicker.clickOnScreen(Clicker.java:106)
at com.robotium.solo.Solo.clickOnScreen(Solo.java:839)
at com.abbottdiabetescare.informatics.sugarsleuth.sherlock.ui.test.ApplicationTest2.testHomeScreenNavigation_StartSensorScreen(ApplicationTest2.java:68)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.runMethod(InstrumentationTestCase.java:214)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.runTest(InstrumentationTestCase.java:199)
at android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.runTest(ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.java:192)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:191)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:176)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:554)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1792)

public class ApplicationTest2 extends
        ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 {
    private Solo solo;

```
public ApplicationTest2(String name) {
    super(HomeActivity.class);
}
@Override
protected void setUp() throws Exception {
    super.setUp();

    Instrumentation instrumentation = getInstrumentation();
    instrumentation.waitForIdleSync();
    Solo.Config config = new Solo.Config();
    config.screenshotFileType = Solo.Config.ScreenshotFileType.PNG;
    solo = new Solo(getInstrumentation(), config);
    getActivity();
}

@Override
protected void tearDown() throws Exception {
    solo.finishOpenedActivities();
    super.tearDown();
}

public void testHomeScreenNavigation_StartSensorScreen() {

    solo.unlockScreen();
    // verify initial state
    solo.assertCurrentActivity("Expected to start on Home Screen",
            HomeActivity.class);
    // activate
    solo.clickOnView(solo.getView(R.id.activationBtn));
    assertTrue(solo.waitForActivity(ActivateActivity.class));
    solo.takeScreenshot("HomeScrnNvgn_StartSensorScreen");
    assertTrue(solo.waitForActivity(ActivateActivity.class));

    solo.clickOnView(solo.getView(R.id.activate_homeBtn));
    assertTrue(solo.waitForActivity(HomeActivity.class));
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately when using robotium you cannot do what you want to do. Android instrumentation (What robotium uses under the covers) has a security model that does not allow you to interact with applications other than the one currently under test, the page that you are seeing must be a different application and that is why you cannot send it events.

Previously I have used a technique where you can intercept the loading of the new application (assuming it is intent driven) using an intent filter. You can see my walkthrough on how to do this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19599435/how-to-verify-redirection-to-google-play-store/20656656#20656656)

Comment: I am trying to click on the same app that I am testing. Only the screen I am trying to click is on full screen mode when android navigation bar are hidden. Robotium is not able to click on this screen. But while on this screen once I touch anywhere using hand on the phone screen(android navigation bar is un-hidden), robotium is able to click the buttons.

Comment: I think the OS is taking over the control when the full screen is displayed, thats why robotium is not able to access the screen to click anywhere. But we can touch woth hand to click on the buttons on this screen.

Comment: As i said, i assumed it was another process. what exactly is on the full screen that shows up?